# Http-Header Field Constant Values

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the `static final String` values for Http-Headers values. There is e.g. [javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) but it does not define values for example like `image/jpg` etc.

Would I have to make my own constants or did I just not find the right container yet?

Comment: These values are called [Internet media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) or MIME types.

Answer (score 5):

Guava has a [MediaType](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html) class with a significantly larger number of media types defined.

Comment: The Spring framework also has a class [`MediaType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) with constants. Although it would probably be overkill to include the Spring framework in your project only for this...

Answer (score 0):

- [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) lib provides [HttpHeaders](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/HttpHeaders.html) class
- If your server runs under a Java EE implementation, you can  also use provided [HttpHeaders](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) class